# Fluid Statics and dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What is difference between static pressure and hydrostatic pressure. If both are same then is it the pressure due to weight of water in fluid static and dynamic condition

Comment: You mean $P=\rho g h$ vs. $P = \tfrac{1}{2} \rho A v^2$